# WPF dynamic menuItems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Trying to add some `MenuItems` dynamically to a pre-defined `<Menu>`

`XAML` :

```
<Window x:Class="FSBEM.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FSBEM"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:FSBEM.Models"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="BEM" Height="471.997" Width="1186.374" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
    WindowState="Maximized" 
    Closing="Window_Closing"
    Icon="/Media/Icons/AppL.ico">

    <Grid Name="MainGrid" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
       <Menu Name="MainMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="23  VerticalAlignment="Top" >
         <MenuItem Name="M_1" Header="1">
              <MenuItem Name="M_2" Header="2"/>
              <MenuItem Name="M_3" Header="3" />
         </MenuItem>
         <MenuItem Name="M_Test" Header="Test"/>
      </Menu>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

`Code-Behind` :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
         InitializeComponent();

         MenuItem mItem1 = new MenuItem();
         mItem1.Name = "MenuItem1";
         mItem1.Header = "MenuItem1";
         M_Test.Items.Add(mItem1);

         MenuItem mItem2 = new MenuItem();
         mItem2.Name = "MenuItem2";
         mItem2.Header = "MenuItem2";
         M_Test.Items.Add(mItem2);
    }
}
```

and here is the result :

[image]

I have no clue what the problem is. Any Help!

**UPDATE**

The Code compiles fine and gives me the result in the picture above.

`Note` :

I created a new project and tested the code. and it works fine!!

Comment: create a complete minimum example plz.

Comment: updated the post.

Comment: Your code does not compile, but works fine when you fix it.

Comment: @vesan my mistake. it was a copy & paste issue. but my code compiles and gives me the result I showed in the post. any way I updated the post.

Comment: "I created a new project and tested the code. and it works fine" then it means you have something in your old project that is responsible for it. For example global style

Answer (score 1):

You did everything right, it's just you're declaring your MenuItem mItem1 but when using it you're writing mItem (you forgot the 1 at the end) same thing for the second one.

This is how the code should be :

```
                MenuItem mItem1 = new MenuItem();
            mItem1.Name = "MenuItem1";
            mItem1.Header = "MenuItem1";
            M_Test.Items.Add(mItem1);

            MenuItem mItem2 = new MenuItem();
            mItem2.Name = "MenuItem2";
            mItem2.Header = "MenuItem2";
            M_Test.Items.Add(mItem2);
```

Comment: that was not the issue. that was a mistake copying and pasting.

Answer (score 0):

In your mainwindow.xaml, you can have something similar to this...

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Name="mainwindow">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding ElementName=mainwindow, Path=Windows}" x:Key="YourMenuItems"/>
     </Window.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=mainwindow}">
        <Menu Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_View" >
                <MenuItem Header="Windows">
                    <MenuItem.ItemsSource>
                        <CompositeCollection>
                            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource MenuItems}}" />                            
                        </CompositeCollection>
                    </MenuItem.ItemsSource>
                    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding MenuItemName}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then in mainwindow.xaml.cs, you can have something like this...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<MenuItem> _menuItems= new ObservableCollection<YourObj>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem{ Title = "Menu Item 1" });
        MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem{ Title = "Menu Item 2" });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> MenuItems
    {
        get { return _menuItems; }
        set { _menuItems= value; }
    }
}

public class YourObj
{
    public string MenuItemName{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: My apology, first of all, in your mainwindow.xaml.cs, you should create an observablecollection which have multiple different menuitems in it; in our case, we have MenuItems as a collection that have multiple different menuitems. Then in the xaml, we can just bind to the observablecollection of MenuItems. this way, you won't need to explicitly declare <menuitem.... > multiple time in the xaml since they are already inside the observablecollections MenuItems